# Unable to Hide Scrollbar in Firefox 115.0.3 (64-bit) Using -webkit-scrollbar CSS Rule

Tags: css

I am facing an issue with hiding the scrollbar in Firefox version 115.0.3 (64-bit) using the `-webkit-scrollbar` CSS rule. The code snippet `::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; }` works perfectly on Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but it appears to be ineffective on Firefox.

I have explored various solutions from similar questions on StackOverflow and other online resources, but none of them have resolved the problem.
I tried the following code:

```
body {
scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

this combination of CSS rules failed to hide the scrollbar in Firefox.

```
/* This CSS rule successfully hides the scrollbar in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

/* Other attempted solution that doesn't work in Firefox either */
body {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: As the name suggests, `-webkit-scrollbar` works only in WebKit based browsers. see https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: But how can i remove scroll bar from my page ? in firefox

Comment: use `scrollbar-width: none;` in the ***container***. your code should work if you want to prevent the scrollbar in body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firefox 64.x.x you can use the `scrollbar-width` property ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width#browser_compatibility ), try with

```
html {
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
```